# HTML tag correction in python

Tags: python, html

Is there any easy way to correct incorrectly closed HTML tags using python? For example I have:

```
<p><b>blabla</p></b>
```

and want to change it to:

```
<p><b>blabla</b></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [pytidylib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytidylib/).

Comment: I did'n want to use a third-party library. But it seems to be the only way.

Comment: @pomel see my updated answer on going without external libraries.

Comment: HTML is a really complex beast. What is "correct" HTML? There's a huge document defining it. Which tags need closing, and if they do, where should the closing tag be added? It's guesswork, and it's definitely not the kind of thing you should want to hack for yourself. Use an external library, and save your coding skills for something more tractable. (Or to improve on the automatic correction you get from the library, if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? E.g. Google: "python tidy html"? Anyway, see this articles:

- http://effbot.org/zone/element-tidylib.htm
- http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/09/08/pyxml.html

If you want do it without external libraries, you can still do it with some regexp replace (e.g. replace every `</p>[^<]*?</b>` (with `re.DOTALL` enabled) to `</b></p>`, *but* [this is not the recommended way to modify/parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11621).